# PHPDocx Find and Replace Issues

Tags: php, docx, phpdocx

I am using PHPDocx to find and replace sentances in word docs, but It is not working for any string that includes a ' or a ".  I have tried escaping these characters with no luck.  Any ideas?

Exaple:

```
You’re being enrolled today.
```

will not be replaced, but

```
You are being enrolled today.
```

will work fine.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

I think It is probably because the text is splitted amongst many tags, eg your text looks like this:

```
<w:t>You</w:t>
<w:t>'re being enrolled today</w:t>
```

That is one reason why it is difficult to do proper search/replace in word.

One way to get around this is to write thing in one row (eg not edit the sentence to add the `'`).

So If you delete the sentence and write it all again, I suspect it might work.

If that still doesn't work, you can also unzip your docx, and go to that sentence in the file word/document.xml and fix the problem with the tags yourself.

If you don't want to encounter that problem at all, you can use a templating engine I created for docx, but works in Node.JS or with the command line: https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater